# php action interfering with css

Tags: php, css

Ok, I have page one(index), fully functional and working fine as is with all content loading into an iframe. However, due to the layout's design, I wanted my portfolio to have more space for viewing, so I created another page for the portfolio (p.html). Now, since there is no way (that I know of or could figure out) to click a link on p.html and tell it to open for example home.html#top within the iframe named "content." So, I toyed with some php and came up with the following code:

```
<?php
  switch($_GET['go']) { 
  case 'home': $src='pages/home.html#top'; break; 
  case 'about': $src='pages/about.html#top'; break; 
  case 'contact': $src='pages/contact.html#top'; break; 
  default: $src='pages/home.html'; break; 
} ?>
```

Then, on index.php, in the iframe I have `<?=$src;?>` set as the source.

Now, when you first load http://www.djcproductions.net, everything works fine, the default page home.html loads in the iframe as it should. However, click on any of the links in the nav bar and it will somehow class with my CSS for the content. If you pay attention when you first go to the site, and scroll down to the text, you can see the background image as the contentstyle.css file is set up for home.html to have a transparent background. But, once you click any link, that goes out the window and the background is not transparent **EDIT** and it also seems to shift the page loaded into the content iframe to the right about fifty pixels. So, since the default line of code for the home.html in the php code worked as it should, I thought maybe it was the #top messing stuff up. So, I removed all the #top tags from the links, and tried it again. Again, on load the page is fine, then I click a link and my whole index.php page loads into the iframe?! My mind is blown. Am I doing this all wrong, or is it just one stupid line I am missing or something?

Comment: Quite rude of someone to vote down and not explain why. I'll vote up just to balance.

Comment: The best solution would be to abandon iframes.

Comment: @Cthulhu my guess is that that was because no effort is shown. What have you tried? Take a look at the `target` attribute of `<a>`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, with the time spent on this project, and the look I am going for I cannot abandon them, I know this can be done, as it is working almost completely, just with a small quirk. What about the target? All of them are set to "content" on index.php, and as far as I know, I cannot link to target "content" on p.php as there is no such iframe on that page. And -Cthulhu, thank you, I do not know why I got voted down, I thought I explained it in depth and provided my work properly?

Comment: Also, if you are using iframes, search engines will probably not index the content as well as it could. Using iframes is also terrible design and relying on them indicates a fundamental design flaw. Also, the fact you are promoting web design using a site that relies on iframes would make me keep well clear of you're 'web design' services!

Comment: I appreciate the ideas given that ney say the use of iframes, it was not my original intention, but it is what is happening, I am asking for input on what would cause the php to interfere with my css.

Comment: php is server side, css is client side, so your analysis makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Dagon, what does not make sense? I know that php is server side and css is client side, the css should continue to be in effect on the page when it loads into the iframe, while the php is doing its job of switching the iframe content on index.php when you click a link on p.php. Is there an obvious reason that using this php method would cause my pages loaded into the "content" iframe to load with all of the font CSS working, but not the background: transparent, as well as shifting everything to the right? Also, Brian, I'm using iframes to reduce the load times because of all the images.

Comment: the issue is nothing to do with php.

Comment: Then why did everything work perfectly before adding the php? I had no issues until using php to load content into an iframe on page b from clicking a link on page a.

Comment: I was trying to debug your code, and it's harder than I thought. Code is pretty messy, sorry. Btw, when you shift to Portfolio, you rendered  a different set of html [no iframes], so targeting your links in "content" will definitely go boo boo.

Comment: There is no iframe on the portfolio (p.php) page, the "content" target is on index.php, that is the entire situation as to why I used php in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the issue of the About Us page not loading. Here is my summary of the issue.

If I manually put `http://www.djcproductions.net/index.php?go=about` in the browser address bar, it all works. This means your PHP switch statement is happy as long as you supply the request paramter.

When I look at your link, it has a target attribute:

```
<a class="about" target="content" href="index.php?go=about">...
```

This means it is loading the whole page into the iframe, which I'm pretty sure is not what you are trying to do.

If you change your hyperlink to:

```
<a class="about" href="index.php?go=about">...
```

It will work. Equally, if you change it to:

```
<a class="about" target="content" href="pages/about.html">...
```

It will work.

Just don't use the target and the full page link together.

Comment: Oh my god. THANK YOU!! I knew it was something stupid I was just overlooking. Thank you for actually being perceptive to my issue, I think I just spent too many days in a row for too many hours at a time staring at all the code between the pages looking for some big complicated issue. One more thing with this that I am not sure if you can help with or not but what if I want to link to the top anchor on the pages/about.html? Normally, I would just do pages/about.html#top, which is what I have in the php but now that I removed the target, it neglects the #top. Any thoughts? Again, thank you!

Comment: Try using `target="_top"` on the link, where you used to have `target="content"`

Comment: Hmm, that did not seem to do anything at all. I will have to look further into this and if I cannot get it I will post a new question regarding this.  Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, disabling right click is annoying for people trying to help you look at problems on your website and is ultimately pointless as I have got to the source anyway.

The problem that shows itself on `p.php` is that your image source for your social network images is incorrect. This causes the alternate text to be displayed (or a broken image glyph) and as your design relies on the size of those images, everything is mis-placed.

Changing the image source on those images fixes this issue.

```
images/p_05.jpg
```

Should be

```
images/image_05.jpg
```

And the same for image_03

There are other issues too, but you need to isolate each one and ask a question specifically about it. If you create a smaller example of your problem it also helps people to help you.

Comment: Oh no, I'm sorry for the no-right click, it serves its purpose for the reason I use it quite well, but I can totally see the inconvenience when you are trying to help! Anyway, I am not sure how those two images got messed up but they are fixed now. Either way, the visual issue occuring is in fact on index.php. The sole purpose of this is so that when you are on p.php, and click on let's say "About Us" at the bottom or top of the page, it will then go to index.php and display pages/about.html into the targeted iframe named "content." However, if you do so, you will see what is happening.

Comment: I ran out of characters- The page loaded into the target iframe is shifted to the right, and the background is no longer transparent.  There is no problem with my css, as this never happened before I added this php action to load the correct page in the iframe. When you first go to http://www.djcproductions.net if you scroll down to the "Welcome !" part, you will see how it should - and did - look before adding the little bit of php listed in my original question. Then click on "About" or "Contact Us" up top and you will see the error at hand.